# Get List of Variable on Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to get the list of the variable using Terraform, below is my directory structure:

```
.
├── main.tf
├── path_modules
│   └── module_name
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── variables.tf
```

I put the variables in `main.tf` file as below:

```
module "module_name"
...
  ssh_users                   = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6", "user7", "user8", "user9"]
  ssh_keys                    = ["user1.pem.pub", "user2.pem.pub", "user3.pem.pub", "user4.pem.pub", "user5.pem.pub", "user6.pem.pub", "user7.pem.pub", "user8.pem.pub", "user9.pem.pub"]
```

Then I put code to get that variable in ./path_module/module_name/main.tf file as below:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "module_name" {
...
  metadata = {
    count = length(var.ssh_keys)
    ssh-keys = format("%s:%s", "${var.ssh_users[count.index]}", file("${path.module}/${var.ssh_keys[count.index]}"))
  }
```

and after try to validate using **terraform validate** I got this error:

```
Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

  on path_module/module_name/main.tf line number, in resource "google_compute_instance" "module_name":
  line number:     ssh-keys = format("%s:%s", "${var.ssh_users[count.index]}", file("${path.module}/${var.ssh_keys[count.index]}"))

The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can only use `count` on the resource level and the `metadata` argument is a mapping.

```hcl
resource "google_compute_instance" "module_name" {
  count = length(var.ssh_keys)

  ...

  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = format(
      "%s:%s",
      "${var.ssh_users[count.index]}", ], 
      file("${path.module}/${var.ssh_keys[count.index]}")
    )
  }
}
```